# How can I "replace" a letter in uppercase only in excel vb.net

Tags: vba

I am writing a script in vb.net and wanted to replace the "N" letter, how can I do it?
It also deletes the letter in the word "online"

thank you.

```
        ws1.Range("F:F").Replace(("N"), "")
```

does also remove the N in "Online" which is the header of column F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the String.Replace() method.

This works:

```
   Dim strOldString As String = "Never replace the lowercase n in online"
   Dim strNewString As String = strOldString.Replace("N", "0")
   Debug.WriteLine(strNewString)
```

Output:

```
   0ever replace the lowercase n in online
```

Here is the [Microsoft documentation for the String.Replace() method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-6.0)

If this solves your question, please mark this as your accepted answer.

Comment: ws1.Range("AB:AB").Replace(("N"), "")
 
I have it like this, how can I change that to your writing?

Comment: Are you trying to replace "N" with nothing?   Try ws1.Range("AB:AB").Replace("N", "")   That will replace "N" with blank nothing (like deleting the N)

Comment: Yeah I try to delete the N besides the one and only line where "online" must persist

also  i can go that way where I mark all the words from "2nd row on" to the end.. because the word Online is a header is coloumn AB1.
Sorry  to mislead my question, but you're still here and work with me on a solution that's a great way to be welcomed here in this forum.

Comment: Yes ... try ...     ws1.Range("AB:AB").Replace("N", "")

Comment: Result is still Olie (in the first line)

Comment: What do you get for  ws1.Range("AB:AB")  ?

Comment: Uhm, I don't understand.
I wanted to replace the N, all the N disappeared but the Header so the first line is deleting the N too. (in Online)

How can I make this only the uppercase N will be deleted?

I guess  ws1.Range("AB:AB") does nothing right?

Comment: Try ws1.Range("AB:AB").Replace(Chr(78),"")    The Chr(78) is only the uppercase N

Comment: Wow, but unfortunately it doesn't delete the "N"

We can also go this way to specify the range since the "Online" is in Row 1... 

How do you pick the range from 2nd row till last?

Comment: To change the range try ws1.Range("AB2:AB").Replace("N", "")  That will start with Cell AB2.  But the .Replace()  should work without changing the range

Comment: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: it says
am I missing something